# Excel VBA FormatConditions drops invalid procedure call or argument on the client

Tags: excel, vba, exception, excel-formula

We have an excel, which contains some VBA code. For a table we write some VBA code to set up some preparation like these:

```
Worksheets("Activity Features").range("ActivityFeaturesTable[ProtonProject]").Formula = "=VLOOKUP([Proton],Table_PT2_Projects,2,FALSE)"
Worksheets("Activity Features").range("ActivityFeaturesTable[SUM]").Formula = "=SUM(ActivityFeaturesTable[@[C0001]:[C0500]])*@IF([@Multiplier]="""",1,[Multiplier])"

With Worksheets("Activity Features").range("ActivityFeaturesTable[StartDate]")
          .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0) = ""From StartDate to EndDate"", FALSE, TRUE)"
End With
```

This *.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression .. * line drops *Invalid procedure call or argument* error, however lines before this executes without any error.

The error occurs only on one client laptop, we cannot reproduce, several other users never experienced this error before. We checked the client computer settings, the *Regional* settings "List separator" was set to ";" instead of "," - but changing back to "," does not helped at all. And VBA code lines before this one also contains "," as separator in the formula.

We wonder why this error happens on the client side on this line?! Any idea? Is there any problem with the INDIRECT or RC in the formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Formulas in Conditional formatting works different than the rest of formulas... I mean, using the standard separator in **cell formulas** it works well even if regionalization set comma as list separator. But in `FormatContitions` formula, you should use the **local separator**.  I do not understand what happens after changing the separator as you say. I hope you were talking about System localization change, not only Excel. So, please, try: `Formula1:="=IF(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"";0) = ""From StartDate to EndDate""; FALSE; TRUE)"` and I think it will work as you need (standard localization ";").

Comment: If it works, as I suppose, you can change the code to work for both cases. I will show you how if you confirm that the above way works.

Comment: Thanks @faneDuru - trying to reach the client, and I will be back!

Comment: Sorry @FaneDuru for being so late. The problem was the , and ; mismatch. I was able to write code to bypass the problem, find out which is needed on the client side, replacing to the correct one. Thanks a lot!